# how to change the time variable in simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I created a model of a system of ODE's. The system contains 3 functions, say **x,y,z** I'd like to investigate.

The problem is that the time variable in the system is not

`t (time)`

but

`omega*t`

where omega has a fixed value. My question is how can I take the new time variable into considerations in my system? thanks.